# NFS files and directories created with wrong permissions from MacOS client

Tags: centos, nfs, mac, umask

I have a simple NFS share setup on CentOS 7 to allow my Mac to manage files in the /var/www/html directory:

/var/www/html 192.168.1.107(all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1001,rw,sync)

Files and directories are created with the correct UID and GID, but the wrong umask:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1001 41 Jul  1 15:05 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1001  6 Jul  1 15:04 test_dir
```

I need the permissions to be 664 and 775 respectively.

I have set the umask for the user (GID 1000) to "umask 000" for testing in  .bashrc

When I log in as that user and touch a file in that directory I get 666 permissions.

This is the mount command I'm using on the Mac:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw,vers=4 www:/var/www/html /mnt/www
```

(www is the name of the CentOS server)

I have completely disable SELinux on this server and verifies that it is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the issue was the umask setting on the Mac machine.  If I update the umask before I copy files to the NFS volume the files end up with the correct permissions.